# Calculate limit as $x$ tends to zero

Tags: calculus

What is $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{\sin(3x)+5}-\sqrt{5}}{x}$

Comment: Ok my bad, It was a simple question, I forgot square root the 5. Then the solution is just derivative of $\sqrt{sin(3x)+5}$ evaluated at 0.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{\sin(3x)+5}-5}{x}\neq \lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{\sqrt{\sin(3x)+5}-5}{x}$$

moreover note that $\sqrt{\sin(3x)+5}-5 \to \sqrt 5 -5 <0$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know what $\sin(0)=0$. Observe that the numerator becomes $\sqrt{5} - 5$ in the limit. Now what happens as to $\frac{\sqrt{5}-5}{x}$ as $x \rightarrow 0$?